# How to get back optimised photos and videos after signing out and signing back in iCloud Account

Tags: ipad, icloud, photos, accounts

I've signed out from my iCloud account recently from my iPad, and then I signed back in. I have enabled the Optimize Storage option for iCloud, hence low resolution copies of some of my photos are stored in my iPad before. However, after the signout and the signin, the photos that were optimised are no longer in my iPad, but still in iCloud Drive.
How do I download these photos and videos in iCloud to my iPad, preserving the metadata(location, timestamp, etc.)

I have a Windows PC with iTunes installed in it(but I doubt I have a backup of the iPad).
The iPad is an iPad 4, iOS 10.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They will re-download automatically when you re-enable iCloud Photos. It may take a little while for it to re-sync the library.

Comment: Thank you. The photos did indeed re-download, I must have quite a bit of optimised photos on iCloud (around 1 GB) so it took a long time.

Comment: Make sure your backups are current.  iCloud Photo Library is not a backup.

Comment: For anyone unsure the best way to back these up outside of photos, you can use privacy.apple.com to export them as a ZIP.